# Display Font Awesome Instead of IMG

Tags: html, css, icons

I simply want to display Font Awesome icons instead of images in a event timeline.  I replaced the 3 posted IMG areas with .fa -  However that Doesn't appear to be correct.  How do I do what I want?  Thanks!  :--)

```css
.event-timeline ul li .single-event .fa {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.event-timeline ul li:nth-child(2n+1) .single-event .fa {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.event-timeline ul li .single-event img {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.event-timeline ul li:nth-child(2n+1) .single-event img {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.event-timeline ul li:nth-child(2n+1) .single-event img {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    
    .event-timeline ul li:nth-child(2n+1) .single-event .fa {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<li><div class="single-event">
 
 <img src="assets/images/UCF-SIGN-IN.png" height="500" alt="event speaker">
 
 <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 
 <p class="event-time">10:00 AM - 10:00 PM</p> <h3>REGISTRATION</h3> <h3>UCF STAFF,</h3> <span>VARIOUS</span>
 
 </div></li>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML. Without knowing how you have replaced the img element with an fa icon it's impossible to be sure what you need to do.

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be any HTML in your question. Don’t put it in comments and please make a snippet we can run to see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: I edited the start post in this thread.  :--)

Answer (score 0):

`.fa` in the css should be correct.

Comment: So, Change .event-timeline ul li .single-event fa to .event-timeline ul li .single-event .fa ?  That Didn't do anything either.  :--)

Comment: Add you HTML & CSS Code here

Comment: I edited the original question in this thread.  :--)